# Why is the distributive law incorrect here?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, boolean-algebra

**I am trying to simplify:**

$(p \lor \neg q) \land (p \lor q) $

One thing, I identify from the table is this:

$(p \lor q) \land (p \lor r) $ is **second distributive law** which becomes $p \lor (q \land r) $

**My steps:**

1. $(p \lor \neg q) \land (p \lor q) $
2. $p \lor (q \lor \neg q) $
3. $p$

[image]

**I watched this video:**
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fXfv1Ru5tzE&pp=ygUebG9naWMgc2ltcGxpZmljYXRpb24gdGF1dG9sb2d5

I was told that, my approach is wrong above.

Comment: Your Step 2 should be $p \lor (q \land \neg q)$, not $p \lor (q \lor \neg q)$.

Comment: Two wrongs making a right. $q\lor\lnot q = T$ and $p\lor T = T$ (not $p$) so your third step is wrong. But as @TonyK points out you should have $q\land \lnot q$ and not $q\lor \lnot q$.  $q\land\lnot q= F$ and so you should actually have $p\lor F$ rather thn $p\lor T$.  And $p\lor F = p$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution:**

1. $(p \lor \neg q) \land (p \lor q)$
2. $p \lor (q \land \neg q) \quad \textit{Second Distributive Law}$
3. $p \lor F \quad \textit{First Inverse Law}$
4. $p$

*First Inverse Law:* $p \land \neg p \equiv F$

Answer (score 1):

> **My steps:**
>
> 1. $(p \lor \neg q) \land (p \lor q) $
> 2. $p \lor (q \lor \neg q) $

No. That should be  $p \lor (q \color{red}\land \neg q) $

> 3. $p$

No. First of all, your $q \lor \neg q$ is equivalent to $\top$, and so you would get $p \lor \top$. Second, $p \lor \top$ is equivalent to $\top$, rather than $p$.  And third: make sure to show that step.

So, correcting this:

1. $(p \lor \neg q) \land (p \lor q) $
2. $p \lor (q \land \neg q) $
3. $p \lor \bot $
4. $p$